# How to set Am and Pm for Clock

Tags: javascript

Hi I'd like to set this clock to switch between Am and Pm i.e. 12:00 p.m....12:00 a.m.

```
setInterval(function(){ time();}, 1000)

function time(){
 var dates = new Date();

 var newDates = dates.toDateString();
 // var clock = dates.toLocaleTimeString();
 var seconds = dates.getSeconds();
 var minutes = dates.getMinutes();
 var hours = dates.getHours();
 var stringSeconds= String(seconds);
 var stringMinutes= String(minutes);
 var stringHours= String(hours);
 newDate.textContent = newDates;
 newDivSeconds.textContent =  stringSeconds;
 newDivMinutes.textContent = stringMinutes + '   :' ;
 newDivHours.textContent = stringHours + '   :';
```

Comment: `String` is unnecessary. Where is your *question-mark*? What's your issue? Can you create a [mcve] and explain what's wrong (and what you tried to solve your own issue)?

Comment: Also: `function pad(num) { return ("0"+num).slice(-2)}`